# How to convert a legacy c++ functions to template

Tags: c++

Say I have bunch of legacy c++ functions that have data type appear both in their function name and in the return type:

```
type_float func_float (float a, float b) { ... }
type_double func_double (double a, double b) {...}
type_int func_int (int a, int b) {...}
...
```

Now I'd like to add a wrapper using c++ template to those functions, something like:

```
template<return_type, input_type> 
return_type func(input_type a, input_type b)
```

Inside this template function, I have to use those existing legacy functions according to input type. Is it possible to achieve this in c++?

Comment: Yes. Use specialized templates.

Comment: You might be better off with a bunch of non-template overloads instead: `type_float func(float a, float b) { return func_float(a, b); } type_double func(double a, double b) { return func_double(a, b); }` and so on. With a template, realize that `return_type` cannot be deduced - you'd have to call it like `func<type_float>(1.0f, 2.0f)` which kind of defeats the point.

Comment: Thanks @SamVarshavchik for your quick reply. I am having trouble to construct legacy function name and return type name using input type. Could you give me some details on this?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You would make the template have only one template parameter, either using traits to specify the return type or else returning `auto`.

Comment: @DavisHerring `auto` won't work - you need to give the general template *some* return type, which specializations would then have to match. Yes, you could do something like `conditional<is_same<input, float>::value, type_float, conditional<is_same<input, double>::value, type_double, ...>>` - but what's the point?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Here's a [very warningful example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OqOCHphIu9qVkc1s) that says we can use `auto` here...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: As for the point, it's to avoid the client having to supply template arguments!

Comment: @DavisHerring What's the point of using a template and specializations, rather than non-template overloads? That's what I was trying to say.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: It is probably better to use overloads; just don't say that a template would _necessitate_ template arguments.